# Carbon object to Unix timestamp based on timezone

Tags: laravel-5, timezone, unix-timestamp, php-carbon

I have a datetime string of format '**Y-m-d H:i:s**', and datetime value as '**2018-01-30 07:11:21**'.

```
$carbon_obj = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s' , '2018-01-30 07:11:21','America/Chicago');
```

*How do it get the Unix timestamp from this carbon object?*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

just add `timestamp` at the back of your code.

```
$carbon_obj = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s' , '2018-01-30 07:11:21','America/Chicago')->timestamp;
```

or

```
$carbon_obj = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s' , '2018-01-30 07:11:21','America/Chicago');
$carbon_obj->timestamp;
```

If you have `data missing` error. missing it is the data your passed it not a complete date format.

Try this.

```
$timestp = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', Carbon::parse($trans['transaction_datetime']) ,Setting::get('timezone'))->timestamp;
```

Comment: tried that but it says error **Exception with message Data missing**

Comment: The code is tested in `php artisan tinker`. You should able to get the result too. I suspect there is another part of your code break it. Try run your `php artisan tinker`

Comment: Yes i tried in tinker it works. In Code also in doing the same thing but it says data missing. Below is the code which is being used

Comment: `$timestp = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s' ,$trans['transaction_datetime'] ,Setting::get('timezone'))->timestamp;`

Comment: can you show me your `$trans['transaction_datetime'] ` output? I updated my answer, you add `Carbon::parse()` inside your date data. It should be worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Carbon::shiftTimezone](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) to change the timezone without changing the dates and time.

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('2020-03-27');
dump($dt);   //2020-03-27 00:00:00.0 Asia/Kolkata (+05:30)
dump($dt->shiftTimezone('utc'));  //2020-03-27 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
```